# Как правильно настроить метод для управления фрагментами

Tags: java, android

```
 public void navigationToFragment(Fragment fragment, Bundle bundle, String strTitle){
        String fragmentName = fragment.getClass().getName();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        boolean isFragmentPop = manager.popBackStackImmediate (fragmentName, 0);
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();

        if (isFragmentPop) fragment=manager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentName);
        if (bundle!=null) fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        if (strTitle!=null) getSupportActionBar().setTitle(strTitle);

        ft.replace(R.id.container,fragment,fragmentName);
        ft.addToBackStack(fragmentName);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

---

`navigationToFragment(new AlbumsGroupFragment(),bundle,model.name);` Вот так вызывается метод.

Проблема в том что если создается фрагмент А, а затем фрагмент Б, то после вызова onBackPressed у Фрагмента А вызывается OnCreateView.

А я хотел чтобы фрагмент А не создавался, а как бы вышел из стека. А то какая - то небылица получается

Comment: Буду благодарен за любые идеи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам во фрагменте в методе `onCreateView` нужно прописать хорошую логику, этого не избежать. Например, у вас стоит какой-то `CheckBox` и нужно сохранить его состояние. Для этого есть метод `onSaveInstanseState"

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanseState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putExtra("checked", checkBox.isChecked());
    super.onSaveInstanseState(outState);
}
```

Теперь в вашем `onCreateView` нужно сделать так

```
if(savedInstanceState != null) {
    checkBox.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBooleanExtra("checked"));
}
```

Таким образом, при уходе в стек данные о чекбоксе сохранятся в бандл и при возвращении на фрагмент обратно выставятся. Сразу скажу, что если создаются проблемы с анимацией, то приходится делать немыслимые хаки, порой дело доходит, до вынесения библиотек в модули и создавания там методов для открытия/закрытия чего-то без анимации